# Best practice for using web services in C# - consumer side

Tags: c#, performance, web-services

I have recently inherited some MVC code which consumes web services.  This code has several base classes that all inherit from one parent, which sets a private member variable to new ServiceClient() when it's instantiated.  I was always under the impression that you should use the web service client with a "using" block.  Does it really matter?  If so, which is more performant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/briantyler/8978701). It describes a way of generating service proxies on the client on the fly using the Castle Dynamic Proxy. The big advantage of this approach is that you do not need to change any client side code when the service interface changes (unless of course that change is a breaking change). It works for all services and there is no need for code generation.

A number of people have blogged about this approach, but this was the implementation that my team finally settled on after using it in a production system.

The performance of a web service is definitely bounded by the traffic over the wire, not how you create the `ServiceClient` and where you stick a using block.